# Exchange 2003 message tracking a domain

Tags: exchange-2003

Is it possible to use Exchange 2003's Message Tracking Center to search for emails received from / sent to a particular domain (e.g. domain.com.au) ?

If not, is there a program that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Message Tracking Center is designed to track a particular message, not do what you're looking for.  It does, however, create a daily log you could look at with (among other tools), the [Microsoft Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659).

You could even use Windows Search to find the domain name as a string inside your Message Tracking Center logs.

Assuming, of course, you have logging turned on, which you may not.  By default, the message tracking center log is at `..Program Files\Exchsrvr\[Exchange server name].log\[yyyymmdd].log`